# Dismissable banner in Android

Tags: android, layout, banner

I would like to show a banner in an Android activity.

The banner should be:

- Aligned at the bottom of the layout
- Take all the width and have relative height (say 100dip)
- Be dismissable

When dismissed the rest of the layout should strech to fill the area that was occupied by the banner.

What's the best way to implement this in Android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set up an `Animation` to slide the banner down, and when it's out of the view (setup a `onAnimationComplete` listener) call it's method : `setVisibility(View.GONE)` so it will not take up space in layout any more.